# How to refactor a long line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I got this piece of code which is raising line length limit exceed Rubocop offence:

```
return organisation_path(current_user.organisation) if current_user.organisation
return session[:previous_url] if session[:previous_url]
return organisation_path(current_user.pending_organisation_id) if current_user.pending_organisation_id
root_path
```

end

The limit exceeds in second last line. I'm trying to refactor this line to solve the Rubocop offense.

My first attempt was to split it like this:

```
return organisation_path(current_user.pending_organisation_id) if
  current_user.pending_organisation_id
```

But it doesn't look readable.

My second attempt was to factor out this line to a method so I created this method:

```
def pending_organization_path_for_current_user
  return organisation_path(current_user.pending_organisation_id) if current_user.pending_organisation_id
end
```

But again the method name is too long and hence the line

```
 pending_organization_path_for_current_user if current_user.pending_organisation_id
```

exceeds the line length and hence the solution is not feasible for me.

So my question as a beginner is how should I consider refactor such cases?

Comment: What about simply breaking the if statement into multiple lines?

Comment: Rubocop will generate Guard Clause offense then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simply breaking the if statement into multiple lines?

```
if current_user.pending_organisation_id
  return organisation_path(current_user.pending_organisation_id)
end
```

Comment: Rubocop will generate Guard Clause offense then.

Comment: can you add the exact code that you wrote that raises this offense?

Comment: I'm sorry. It doesn't raise Guard Clause but I thought it would.

Comment: That's a solution but I'm worried that its increasing the size of the method. Is it fine from code quality point of view?

Comment: Can't see any issues regarding code quality. It's a lot more readable than a one liner as well.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks a lot. I thought about this solution at first but because I had seen lot of earlier examples where in such cases Guard clause error was raised I thought that this solution won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
return organisation_path(current_user.organisation) if current_user.organisation
return session[:previous_url] if session[:previous_url]
return root_path unless current_user.pending_organisation_id
organisation_path(current_user.pending_organisation_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to tweak Rubocop's settings to alter the accepted style, so you could fix it like this:

```
if current_user.pending_organisation_id
  organisation_path(current_user.pending_organisation_id)
end
```

However, sometimes it is easier just to accept that this is one of those times
where you know better than Rubocop, so just add an exception:

```
# rubocop:disable Style/WhateverLineLengthIsCalled
return organisation_path(current_user.pending_organisation_id) if current_user.pending_organisation_id
# rubocop:enable Style/WhateverLineLengthIsCalled
```